# Apache Beam dataflow on GCS: ReadFromText from multiple path

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-storage

I was wondering if it was possible to use the `ReadFromText` PTransform passing it multiple path.

My PTranform expand method is:

```
def expand(self, pcoll):
    dataset = (
        pcoll
        | "Read Dataset from text file" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(self._source)
```

And `source` right now is a string with a path with a blob pattern
`self._source="gs://bucket1/folder/*`

From the documentation it says:

```
Args:
      file_pattern (str): The file path to read from as a local file path or a
        GCS ``gs://`` path. The path can contain glob characters
        (``*``, ``?``, and ``[...]`` sets).
```

But even if it works greatly if I use `gs://folder/*.gz` (I have multiple files under a path) I can't seem to make it work if I have different path (or, in my case, in different buckets).

I tried with the command `ls` with something like:

```
gsutils ls gs://{bucket1/folder,bucket2/folder}/*
```

But if I try it with the beam pipeline it doesn't work and gives me

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.flex-template.run) unrecognized arguments:
```

Is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: I could actually create two pipeline, or make a `for` loop in order to read those different pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you explained in your comment, you can solve it with a for loop on the `Beam` `Pipeline`, example :

```py
bucket_paths = [
  "gs://bucket/folder/file*.txt",
  "gs://bucket2/folder/file*.txt"
]

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
    for i, bucket_path in enumerate(bucket_paths):
       (p 
        | f"Read Dataset from text file {i}" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(bucket_path)
       
         .... 
       )
```

Comment: That will work. You can also use [Flatten](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=flatten#apache_beam.transforms.core.Flatten) to produce a single PCollection if it makes processing easier.

Comment: @BrunoVolpato can you show me an example of flatten used with ReadFromText?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174629/how-to-flatten-multiple-pcollections-in-python-apache-beam